# Очистка памяти динамического массива строк

Tags: c, динамические-массивы

Доброго времени суток. Есть такая задача. Вводится строка, программа должна разбить ее на лексемы, сохранить их в массив `data`, выполнить какие-то операции и потом успешно завершится. С алгоритмом проблем нет, но вот очистка памяти не работает. Если что, точно известно: количество слов точно не может быть более 25, длина слова - не более 20 символов.

```
int main()
{
    char* string = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 500);
    fgets(string, 500, stdin);

    char** data = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * 25);
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        data[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 20);
    }

    int length = 0;
    data[length] = strtok(string, " ");
    length++;

    while (data[length - 1] != NULL)
    {
        data[length] = strtok(NULL, " ");
        length++;
    }

    //Do Something

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        free(data[i]);
    }
    free(data);
    free(string);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как только вы делаете вот этот финт:

```
data[length] =
```

т.е. присваиваете указателю новое значение, старое, указывающее на выделенную память, теряется. Получается утечка памяти.

А затем вы пытаетесь удалять то, что не выделяли.

Или просто используйте массив указателей, или, если выделяете память для хранения слов - копируйте слова в выделенную память.

**Update**
Вариант 1:

```
int main()
{
    ...
    char** data = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * 25);
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) data[i] = NULL;

    int length = 0;
    for(char * с = strtok(string, " ");c;c = strtok(NULL, " "))
    {
        data[length++] = c;
    }
    //Do Something

    free(data);
    free(string);
}
```

Вариант 2:

```
int main()
{
    ...
    char** data = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * 25);
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) data[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 20);

    int length = 0;
    for(char * с = strtok(string, " ");c;c = strtok(NULL, " "))
    {
        strcpy(data[length++],c);
    }
    //Do Something

    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        free(data[i]);
    }
    free(data);
    free(string);
}
```

Я бы все же добавил проверки на количество слов и длину... Мало ли кто что обещает...

Comment: Извините,  не понял. Можно пример кода?

Comment: Смотрите обновленный ответ.

Comment: `calloc(25, sizeof(char) * 20);` и проблем на порядок меньше сразу. Ещё лучше объявить `struct line { char data[20]; }; lines = calloc(25, sizeof(struct line));`

Comment: @0andriy, а еще лучше для копирования токена вызывать strdup

Answer (score 4):

Для копирования выдаваемого `strtok()` слова в динамическую память проще всего использовать функцию [strdup](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup)

```
#ifndef _GNU_SOURCE
#define _GNU_SOURCE // for getline() with gcc -std=c11, c99 etc...
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char **
get_25words (char *s, size_t *nw)
{
  char **w = (__typeof__(w))malloc(sizeof(char *) * 25); // type cast for c++

  for (*nw = 0; *nw < 25; (*nw)++, s = 0) {
    char *t = strtok(s, " ");
    if (t)
      w[*nw] = strdup(t);
    else
      break;
  }

  return w;
}


int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  char *s = 0;
  size_t sz;

  while (getline(&s, &sz, stdin) > 0) {
    size_t nw;
    char **w = get_25words(s, &nw);

    printf("found %zu words\n", nw);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nw; i++) {
      printf("%s\n", w[i]);
      free(w[i]);
    }
    free(w);
  }

  free(s);
}
```

А читать строки неопределенной длины очень удобно функцией [getline](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline)

Comment: А какой смысл в двойном буферизировании? `getline()` уже выделила память.

Comment: По условиям вопроса -- "разбить ее на лексемы, сохранить их в массив data, выполнить какие-то операции". Тут все дело в **какие-то операции**. В общем случае лучше выделить под каждое слово отдельный блок памяти, который потом может "путешествовать" по структурам данных (списки, множества и т.п.) независимо от остальных. В куче частных случаев -- согласен, все слова строки могут сохраняться в одном блоке (который заполняет `getline()`, тогда в `while(getline(&s, ...))` достаточно обнулять `s`) А тут getline повторно использует уже выделенную в `s` память для следующей строки.